# Does Exoplayer download a chunk completely before processing (decoding) it

Tags: exoplayer2.x, mpeg-dash

Does Exoplayer download a chunk completely before processing (decrypting, decoding) it. Is there a way to override this and start decoding / playback before the chunk is completely downloaded.The content is an MPEG-DASH content with a 6 second chunk size.

I am on the latest version of Exoplayer. I am trying to improve the Video Start Time and hence this query. Also, will smaller chunk sizes impact the Video start time ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean a dash segment when you say chunk - the terminology is important because DASH segments can contain subsegments, and each of these may be decodable, but it is also confusing as the term chunks and segments are both used in the ExoPlayer code.

Its useful when discussing this area to remember that the video download is actually a series of requests and responses, rather than a constant stream of media.

To start decoding earlier you typically have to request smaller 'pieces' (trying to avoid tripping over terminology...) of the video.

To be decodable, and video piece usually needs to start with a frame which does not reference any previous frames - an IDR frame or Stream Access Point (SAP).

Looking at ExoPlayer itself, you can set the number of segments you can download per chunk (Exoplayer terminology for the bit of the video you download) - take a look at the 'maxSegmentsPerLoad' attribute in the 'DefaultDashChunkSource': https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/bd54394391b0527893f382c9d641b8a55ffca765/library/dash/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/source/dash/DashChunkSource.java

However, I think this is the opposite of what you are looking for - you would like to request a smaller piece of video - e.g. subsegments rather than the whole segments.

For that you most likely want to look at the new low latency mechanisms introduced for DASH and for HLS - ExoPlayer has added support for these and there is a public design document which provides a very good explanation of the background and the approach here (link correct at the time of writing - original ExoPlauer git issue also for reference - https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4904):

- https://docs.google.com/document/d/1z9qwuP7ff9sf3DZboXnhEF9hzW3Ng5rfJVqlGn8N38k/edit#

The diagrams in this document explain it well, but the short answer to your question is that yes, this approach does allow smaller 'pieces' of video be downloaded and played back and it does indeed help with video start time.

Comment: Thanks @Mick. I will refer the links provided by you.